# HIVE Count number of value in a column and aggregate

Tags: sql, hive

I have 1 table with 3 columns :

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        ID           |      IDGROUP     |     Parent       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         4        |        Y         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         4        |        N         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         5        |        N         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         4        |        N         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         6        |        Y         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to add a new column and count the number of non-parent (N) in each group like this :

```
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|----------|
|        ID       |      IDGROUP     |     Parent       |   Count  |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|----------|
|        1        |         4        |        Y         |     2    |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|--------- |
|        2        |         4        |        N         |     2    |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|----------|
|        3        |         5        |        Y         |     0    |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|----------|
|        5        |         6        |        Y         |     0    |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|----------|
```

i need to count the number of "N" under an "Y"'s group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when parent <> 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by idgroup) as num_nonparents
from t;
```

Comment: I already tried something like that but it take to much time and it dosen't count by "idgroup" the partition is not working in this case

Comment: I managed to do this with "good" performances with a subquery (distinct col..., sum...) and then an inner join adding all my cols

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT id, idgroup, parent, COUNT(id) as count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY idgroup, parent
```

Comment: it won't do what i want at all... i need to count the number of "N" under an "Y" group

Comment: can you make a small sample of the expected result?

Comment: There's an exemple in the original post